# How to get MonoDevelop to target .NET 2.0 framework with C# 4.0 compiler?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, mono, monodevelop

This is easily possible using Visual Studio, though I need to achieve this using MonoDevelop because Visual Studio compiled DLL's are not playing nice with Unity. MonoDevelop DLL's are working fine but I want to use default function parameters (a C# 4.0 feature) whilst targeting the .NET 2.0 runtime.

Is this possible with MonoDevelop? How can I set this up?

**ADDED: Build Command Lines for Visual Studio and MonoDevelop**

I have sorted arguments for easier comparison:

*MonoDevelop : Target = Mono / .NET 4*

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
/noconfig
/warn:4
"/define:TRACE"
/optimize+
"/out:C:\TestLibraries\TestEditor\bin\Release\TestEditor.dll"
/t:library

/nologo

"/r:C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll"
"/r:C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll"
"/r:C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEditor.dll"
"/r:C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll"

/fullpaths
/utf8output
```

*MonoDevelop : Target = Mono / .NET 3.5 (1st interesting one)*

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe
/warn:4
"/define:TRACE"
/optimize+
"/out:C:\TestLibraries\TestEditor\bin\Release\TestEditor.dll"
/t:library

/nologo
-nostdlib

"/r:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll"
"/r:C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll"
"/r:C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEditor.dll"
"/r:C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll"

/fullpaths
/utf8output
```

*Visual Studio : Target = .NET 4*

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe
/noconfig
/nowarn:1701,1702
/warn:4
/define:TRACE
/optimize+
/out:obj\Release\TestEditor.dll
/target:library

/nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt

/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll"

/debug:pdbonly
/filealign:512
```

*Visual Studio : Target = .NET 3.5 (2nd interesting one)*

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe
/noconfig
/nowarn:1701,1702
/warn:4
/define:TRACE
/optimize+
/out:obj\Release\TestEditor.dll
/target:library

/nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt

/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll"
/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll"

/debug:pdbonly
/filealign:512
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2.0 C# compilers (mcs/gmcs) that comes with the latest stable Mono version (2.10.9) support default function parameters. I just created a new console project, changed the target framework to 2.0 and compiled default function parameters successfully.

Comment: It seems that on Windows Mono is using the Microsoft C# compiler in a different way to which Visual Studio does. Is there a way to force it to use the Mono one?

Comment: I believe you can choose in MonoDevelop's Preferences/.NET Runtimes.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here:

Q1) How do I build a .Net 2.0 compatible .dll or .exe with the current MonoDevelop?

A: I don't know if you *can*.  A workaround is to download and install MonoDevelop 2.4.x.

Q2) I want C# 4.0 default function parameters, but I want to target .Net 2.0

A: You can't :)  If you want to target .Net 2.0, then you need to use that subset of C# language features that's .Net 2.0 compatible.  If you want to use C# 4.0 language features, then you're probably going to need at least *some* .Net 4.0 libraries ... which effectively means you're going to need .Net 4.0.

Comment: I don't know a lot about this, but I read on a couple of StackOverflow answers that in Visual Studio this was possible because default parameters are only a language feature of C# 4 and do work with .NET 2.0 Thanks

Comment: In this case, the "language" is often closely linked to the .Net runtime.  There are two issues: 1) which (potentially new, incompatible) .Net assembly might be needed, and what (potentially new, incompatible)  byte code the compiler will generate for a given language feature.  You can roll the dice ... but there are multiple ways to lose. :(  This link explains the latter problem in more detail: [Common Intermediate Language Infrastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure)

Comment: After additional experimentation I have found that Visual Studio always uses the latest C# compiler from the .NET 4 framework even when target framework is set to "3.5", it just assumes the specified framework instead. MonoDevelop uses the specified framework, but it also uses the C# compiler from the specified framework. I will amend my question with the command lines that are used by VC and MD.